# Does there always exist a lift of a path from $Y$ to $X$ if $f: X\to Y$ is a continuous surjective function?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If one has a continuous surjective function $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ and let $\gamma$ be a continuous path in $Y$, under what circumstances can one find a (possibly non-unique) lifted path $\gamma'$ in $X$ such that $f\circ\gamma'=\gamma$? Can somebody give a counterexample to this always holding?

In particular, does it hold in metric spaces?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_lifting_property. This may be helpful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not necessarily hold in metric spaces. Let $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1$ be given by 
$$f(x)=e^{ix}$$
Let $g:[0,1]\to S^1$ be given by 
$$g(x)=e^{i(x-1/2)}$$
Then this path cannot be lifted.

Answer (score 0):

If your $f$ is also a covering map, there exists a unique lift $\gamma'$. It is unique in the sense that if $x$ is in the fiber of $f$ over $\gamma(0)$, there is a unique lift starting at this point $x$. This comes as a corollary to the homotopy lifting property since a path $\gamma$ can be viewed as a homotopy between two maps from a one-point space into $Y$.

In a more general setting, the lifting criterion is also helpful:
http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101002/downloads/lecture18.pdf

It is given in Theorem 18.1 here

Comment: A lift to a covering space need not be unique. The path in my answer lifts to $x\mapsto x-1/2+2\pi k$ for any $k$ if we extend the domain to all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I left out some stuff there. If $x$ is any point in the fiber of $f$ over $\gamma(0)$, then there exists a unique lift $\gamma'$ such that $\gamma'(0) = x$. Sorry about that.